# Block external access to swf

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have implemented an SWF application which I host to my website and use object and embed tags to load it in.

I observed that the same SWF file is referenced by external websites using the above html tags. Is there a way to block these references?

I tried setting X-Frame-Options to SAMEORIGIN but it didn't work.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You mean other websites "steal" your swf? The browser should allow it without policy files.

Comment: Could use `loaderInfo` to check your SWF location on each run. [**Example code**](http://snipplr.com/view/28103/as3-get-url-of-current-flash-movie-swf/) where `if (myUrl == "https://example.com") { startApp(); } else { showError(); }` where function `startApp` kick-starts the usual running of your app

Answer (score 1):

If they steal your SWF to put it on their domain, use VC.One's advice. Then, if they are hotlinking it... let's do some magick.

When SWF loads a **relative** url, the request (luckily) goes via browser and browser retrieves the url relative to the topmost document frame.

Regardless, your SWF still belongs to your domain, so its security sandbox does.

Split your SWF into 2 parts (lets name them Outer and Inner, Outer starts first, then it loads Inner) that does not work without each other (share classess, access each other display list, etc). Domainlock them to your domain, so none of them starts from other domain. And a final move: Let Outer load Inner via **relative** url.

- If evil guys put both SWFs on their site, they won't start via domainlock.
- If evil guys hotlink Outer SWF, it will try to load Inner SWF from the wrong place.
- If evil guys copy Inner to their site so Outer loads it via relative link, Inner and Outer will have security violation trying to access each other's content.

If splitting the SWF is not an option, there's still more complicated solution with the use of server-side script.

**UPD**.

Lets say your application have class A that uses class B. In order to make the technique above work you need to compile Outer with class B only and Inner with class A only, and where A uses B instead of compile-time access **import B** you should use run-time assess **B = getDefinition("B") as Class**. If genuine Outer loads genuine Inner properly, then getDefinition("B") will indeed return class reference to B and all B functionality will be available. In any other case getDefinition("B") will fail and A will not be able to function properly.

Comment: Interesting, can you write more about. It was always confusing me... Long time ago I tried to load swf from `mydamainA.com` and display it inside page on `mydomainB.com` but I couldn't. I read something aobiut policy file but I didn't understand that and to be honest I still did't learned it as for today (well i couldn't find any details except sentence "you need to use policy files") Now I learn from you that I need to take some special steps to block it this way - I didn't do anything buy myself to block something like that as far as I can tell, my intention was opposite ;)

Comment: Thanks, I would really need to sit on this for while. Right now I don't even have a need for doing such thing so it's just curiosity, so don't need to worry. If I understand you right , you are describing loading swf by another swf but I was actually saying that I had only single .swf on `mydomainA` which was not loading at all in raw HTML page on `mydomainB` but It was loading fine on `mydomainA`.

Comment: @PawełAudionysos I understand that, that's why I said you need to **Split your SWF into 2 parts** in order for this to work. And I also said that **If splitting the SWF is not an option, there's still more complicated solution with the use of server-side script.**

Comment: Now I'm really confused I thought it was solution for OP and to for me how . How we can have one solution for two opposite problems ? :)

Comment: @PawełAudionysos Indeed, my bad. For your case SWF on domain B **must** have a line of code that allows domain A to access it: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Security.html#allowDomain() Basically, you cannot allow yourself into someone's SWF unless that SWF explicitly allows you to.